# Sending weekly emails with job postings internally

Tags: communication

We post a new position online about once a week. Is sending an email organization-wide every time a job is posted too much? Why?

This is in the US, and our org. is a private university. I'm in the HR office.

**Background**:
A part of recruiting employees at a university is fulfilling an affirmative action and disability recruitment duty to try to recruit from minority/disability groups or organizations.

Our senior leadership is considering that since we employ minorities and people who know minorities, sending our job postings to everyone would satisfy this requirement. So, they are considering sending a company-wide email from our official email address when jobs post and creating an announcement on our intranet page (we use Drupal).

**Commentary**:
I feel like it will be an oversaturation and our actual important messages will be lost, or our actual important announcements will be buried. If I'm concerned over nothing though, I would also like to know.

Comment: Have you suggested a biweekly/monthly newsletter with job postings?

Comment: Our job posting email comes daily.  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any mail could be considered SPAM by someone, so I would stay away from blasting to everyone on a weekly basis.  Pretty soon people will just start ignoring you.

A better solution might be to build an internal web portal (if you don't already have one) with all of the open job postings and an option to opt-in to immediate  or summary(weekly?) emails when postings are added or changed.  People who want the mail can get it and other s can just visit the portal when they are interested.

Comment: Perfect solution.

Answer (score 1):

I can see some value in sending these email blasts once a week, especially if it meets a diversity requirement. However, make sure you send in such a way that people can easily manage messages using rules. For example:

- Send from a dedicated email address such as jobs@university.edu. This will prevent your other email addresses from getting junked.
- Prefix with a specific qualifier like "[Job] HVAC Technician"

I would do both.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say sending a new email with each posting is overdoing it. If I needed to highlight new jobs via email, I'd do it on a weekly basis (with an email, or a mention in a weekly electronic newsletter) and help train your audience to go to the site where jobs are posted (create a simple, memorable, vanity URL for it).